# What is the best and easiest setup for enforcing SSL within an entire rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm looking for a fast and maintainable setup of enforcing SSL in production mode.

Are there any gems for that or what is the best practice here? 
And what is the easiest way to test this in development?

The app is hosted on Heroku with the SSL-Addon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `environments/production.rb` (and / or `development.rb`) add the following config:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

This will force app-wide redirects to `https` whenever an unsecure URL was requested.

If you want to test this in development, you should set up a self-signed certificate for your local domain (`localhost` or `my.local` or whatever). For **apache** you can try something like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-12-04), for **ngnix** something like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-12-04/).